# How to use same src file after i run grunt

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

here is my folder structure

app

- index.html
- css folder
- js folder
- src folder

build

- index.html
- minified css
- minified js

my src folder has angular.min.js and all other supporting files. Now I run grunt and move all css html and js files to build folder. But html is still referring to app/src folder which is not inside build. I don't want to create one more src folder inside build. I want to refer same folder which is inside app from build/index.html. How can I do these changes when I run grunt?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just relative paths that you need to update in your built source files, you can always use something like [grunt-rewrite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rewrite) to do a global glob find/replace. It's fast, it's easy to configure, and doesn't muck with your source.